# How to use type in Chart component?

Tags: svelte-chartjs

I am trying to use a single Chart component and change the type either inside the dataset or directly in the component prop but only line and bar work.

I can make line and bar chart work but if I change the type to radar o pie it doesnt work. Do i have to import anything?

Comment: Try to import radar component like `import Radar from "svelte-chartjs/src/Radar.svelte" `

Comment: Is it not possible to use the Chart component?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.